# Reactjs-like animation lib?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, reactjs

So I've been searching around for a js library that replicates reactjs animation features, but isn't attached to a larger lib (such as angular's ng-animate). I've seen a few standalones floating around, but most of them either lack features or their docs are terrible. Note, I'm trying not to make this a "what's the best lib" question to avoid opinion - I'm simply asking what's the closest standalone library to react's animation features (can depend on JQuery).

Comment: I answered this, but for future reference, "What's the best.." type questions aren't appropriate for stack overflow and will quickly be closed by the mods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the Greensock Animation Platform (GSAP) which is superior to pretty much every animation lib in existence.

Seriously. Nothing else is even close.

http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/

Comment: perfect! Exactly what I was looking for :)